# This of inner function when invoked by call

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var outer = function(){
    var that = this;
    function inner(){
        assert(this===that, "Inner === Outer");
        console.log(this);
        console.log(that);
    }
    inner();
    return this;
};

outer();
var obj = {};
outer.call(obj);
```

When the first invocation is executed - outer(). Everything is clear for me - the outer is called in window context and both this and that === window. Then things get wired when I invoke function outer be call function. That === obj, which is obvious, but why this === window ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're losing the context by introducing a closure. `this` depends only on **how you call the function**. It can be implicit, as in the case of an object method. In your code `inner` is not being called with any context so it'll default to `window`. You can do this:

```
var outer = function(){
    var that = this;
    function inner(){
        assert(this===that, "Inner === Outer");
        console.log(this);
        console.log(that);
    }
    inner.call(this); // explicit context
    return this;
};
```